# finding the longest prefix contained in a dictionary

Tags: c++, algorithm, data-structures, zip

I'm implementing Lempel-Ziv compression and a question springs to mind.

Given a 'dictionary' and a string of characters. I want to be able to compute the longest prefix og the string, that is contained in the dictionary.

That is given strings:

```
0 : AABB
1 : ABA
2 : AAAB
```

and the query string 'AABBABA' I would like to be able to do the a lookup that returns '0' this should be done in time linear to the length of the prefix.

Next of I would like to be able to add the new prefix 'AABBAB' to the dictionary in constant time.

Is there a standard, and easy way/algorithm for doing this?

My original idea was to build a standart n-way tree with a list of pointers and just search this?

Comment: Does "linear time" imply you want the complexity of a dictionary lookup to be independent of the alphabet size S, too? The "standard n-way" tree, from the sounds of it, could have up to S outgoing edges per node.

Comment: @jogojapan: you are correct, I mean linear with regards to the length. and for constant, if mean linear in the alphabet ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are describing a simple [trie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) lookup, except that you would return a leaf node even when there are excess characters.

Not sure what you're thinking of with an n-way tree, but most likely it's exactly the same, since it's the obvious solution :v) . If you want to be more efficient, you can look into different kinds of tries.

Comment: How does adding "the new prefix 'AABBAB'" work in constant time in a simple search trie?

Comment: @jogojapan: by holding the node returned, and just adding the tail :-)

Comment: Ok. Admittedly, I interpreted "simple trie" as one that has individual characters on the transitions. Maybe my mistake.